# Display Bootstrap Vue columns one below the other in mobile view

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Bootstrap Vue library for my columns, I display 3 cards per row and it looks fine on desktop but it's looking way too small on mobile so I want to display those 3 cards one below the other just on mobile. How can I do this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
.card{
    background-color: #BAE5FF !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 0px 0px !important;
}

.work-link{
    color: #172e54;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-row>
    <b-col cols="4" sm="4" md="4">
      <b-card no-body style="max-width: 20rem;" img-src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" img-alt="Image" img-top>
        <template v-slot:header>
          <a href="" class="work-link text-center"><h5 class="mb-0"><strong>1</strong></h5></a>
         </template>

      </b-card>
    </b-col>
    
    <b-col cols="4" sm="4" md="4">
      <b-card no-body style="max-width: 20rem;" img-src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" img-alt="Image" img-top>
        <template v-slot:header>
          <a href="" class="work-link text-center"><h5 class="mb-0">                   <strong>2</strong></h5></a>
         </template>
       </b-card>
    </b-col>
    
    <b-col cols="4" sm="4" md="4">
      <b-card no-body style="max-width: 20rem;" img-src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" img-alt="Image" img-top>
        <template v-slot:header>
          <a href="" class="work-link text-center"><h5 class="mb-0"><strong>3</strong></h5></a>
        </template>
      </b-card>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</div>
```

Comment: Column props sm, md, lg, xl indicate the number of columns you'd like to use out of the possible 12 per row, at the various breakpoints. So, if you want three equal-width columns at breakpoint sm, you can use <b-col sm="4">. the special value auto can be used to take up the remaining available column space in a row.

Comment: this is not what I want, what I want is to display each card one below the other in mobile view, but still displaying the 3 cards in the same row in desktop, so using sm md lg didn't do anything for me, even if i use for example sm="12" md="4" lg="4".

Comment: sm="1" maybe more suitable?

Comment: welp, still doesn't work :(

Comment: can you create a live example in something like jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fysma7t0/

Comment: I made typo. I mean to set "12" not "1". This was already mentioned by Vinay Pai.

Comment: @FlowMafia I think you misunderstood the "cols" attribute. It doesn't specify the number of columns... that is fixed at 12. Cols specifies the width of the column at the "XS" size.

Comment: yeah i fixed it removing the "cols" attribute and just leaving the sm and md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap layout always has 12 columns, the `cols`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`, and `xl` attributes specify how many of those columns you want an element to take up at various sizes. Somewhat confusingly, the smallest breakpoint (`xs`) is specified using the `cols` attribute. If the total size of columns exceeds 12, it will start a new row.

So if you want them to stack on mobile, you need to set the the `cols`attribute to 12 so that each card takes up the full row on mobile.